# chrome/opera anchor shift away after adding dom elements

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, anchor, opera

Say I have a URL: http://rythmengine.org/doc/expression.md#transformer

Immediately after the page is loaded, the anchor is shown correctly, however I have a script to automatically add some iframes across the page, chrome/opera will later on shift away from the anchor `#comment`, firefox and IE (10) are all good.

Any idea how to fix it in Chrome/opera?

Comment: good luck on finding an answer from a credible source. this is a very specific question. I do not think you can find an answer from an official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When every iframe ends loading tell the browser to go to that hash

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    document.location.href = document.location.hash;
});
```

Comment: Actually this solution is neat and I use it in my real project

Comment: For people who are curious, here is the final solution: https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm-website/blob/master/app/rythm/Doc/load.html#L250

Comment: i wonder if using $('iframe:last-child') would be more efficient

Comment: not sure if the iframe load event get triggered by order. Anyway the `ifCnt = ifCnt - 1;if(ifCnt == 0)` doesn't cost too much, right?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if I would implement this or not since the iframes do take a noticeable amount of time to load and the user might already be scrolling around the page and get jolted back to the hash element but here is a solution I came up with using jQuery.

Since the iframes are being replaced in the document after it initially loads you can use the `.load()` function which normally never fires if you just have it on the document.

### **Demo** on [this page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MadLittleMods/cDrVR/show/#comments) and [edit the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/cDrVR/).

Just add this jQuery code into your script tag where you replace all of the `pre code`:

**Code:**

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    moveToHash();
});

// Scroll to the url hash element
function moveToHash()
{
    var hashElem = $(window.location.hash);

    // If the hash elment exists
    if(hashElem.length)
    {
        window.scrollTo(hashElem.position().left, hashElem.position().top);
    } 
}
```

*Edit:* had a few mistakes and unnecessary in the code that are now fixed.

Comment: thx it works after I put `window.scrollTo` logic inside a `setTimeout` call back function